# An identity satisfied by the middle binomial coefficient

Tags: reference-request, binomial-coefficients

Is there a citable reference for the identity

> $$\frac{ \binom{n}{n/2+1}-\binom{n}{n/2+2} }{ \binom{n}{n/2}-\binom{n}{n/2-1} }=\frac{3n}{n+4}$$

for every *even* natural number $n\geq 1$?

I know how to prove this, and am not asking for a proof, only for a reference, because the proof I found is unpleasantly lengthy.

Comment: Note that the expression can be simplified by cancelling the factor of $n + 2$.

Comment: @TheoBendit: thanks. It is quite funny that I overlooked this. Unsurprisingly, the proofs I have are not significantly simplified by this cancelling of a factor, and my hope for a reference remains. But thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following identity holds (see the fourth one [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_involving_binomial_coefficients)):
$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n+1-k}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}$.
Hence
$$\binom{n}{n/2+2}=\frac{n+1-(n/2+2)}{n/2+2}\binom{n}{n/2+1}=\frac{n-2}{n+4}\binom{n}{n/2+1}$$
and
$$\binom{n}{n/2}=\frac{n/2+1}{n+1-(n/2+1)}\binom{n}{n/2+1}=\frac{n+2}{n}\binom{n}{n/2+1}$$ 
Hence
$$\frac{ \binom{n}{n/2+1}-\binom{n}{n/2+2} }{ \binom{n}{n/2}-\binom{n}{n/2-1} }=\frac{ \binom{n}{n/2+1}-\frac{n-2}{n+4}\binom{n}{n/2+1} }{ \frac{n+2}{n}\binom{n}{n/2+1} -\binom{n}{n/2+1} }=\frac{1-\frac{n-2}{n+4}}{\frac{n+2}{n}-1}=\frac{3n}{n+4}.$$

Comment: This is great. Of course I knew the identity mentioned at the beginning, but I did not think of doing it this way. This seems unsurpassable in in simplicity. I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The proof certainly isn't immediate, however it doesn't seem very lengthy (to me, at least)...

> $$\frac{ \binom{n}{n/2+1}-\binom{n}{n/2+2} }{ \binom{n}{n/2}-\binom{n}{n/2-1} }=\frac{n(3n+6)}{(n+2)(n+4)}$$

For even $n$ let's substitute $n=2k$:

$$\frac{ \binom{2k}{k+1}-\binom{2k}{k+2} }{ \binom{2k}k-\binom{2k}{k-1} } = \frac{2k(6k+6)}{(2k+2)(2k+4)}$$
Now we expand binomial coefficients with ratios of respective factorials on LHS and reduce RHS a bit:
$$\frac{ \frac{(2k)!}{(k+1)!(2k-(k+1))!}-\frac{(2k)!}{(k+2)!(2k-(k+2))!} }{ \frac{(2k)!}{k!(2k-k)!}-\frac{(2k)!}{(k-1)!(2k-(k-1))!} } = \frac{12k(k+1)}{4(k+1)(k+2)}$$
$$\frac{ \frac{(2k)!}{(k+1)!(k-1)!}-\frac{(2k)!}{(k+2)!(k-2)!} }{ \frac{(2k)!}{k!k!}-\frac{(2k)!}{(k-1)!(k+1)!} } = \frac{3k(k+1)}{(k+1)(k+2)}$$

Let's reduce $(2k!)$ from enumerators of all the terms on LHS and $(k+1)$ on RHS:

$$\frac{ \frac 1{(k+1)!(k-1)!}-\frac 1{(k+2)!(k-2)!} }{ \frac 1{k!k!}-\frac 1{(k-1)!(k+1)!} } = \frac{3k}{k+2}$$

Now let's reduce $k!k!$ from denominators:

$$\frac{ \frac k{k+1}-\frac {(k-1)k}{(k+1)(k+2)} }{ \frac 11-\frac k{k+1} } = \frac{3k}{k+2}$$
Now $(k+1)(k+2)$ from denominators:
$$\frac{ k(k+2)- (k-1)k }{ (k+1)(k+2) - k(k+2) } = \frac{3k}{k+2}$$
$$\frac{ [(k+2)- (k-1)]k }{ [(k+1)-k](k+2) } = \frac{3k}{k+2}$$
$$\frac{ 3\cdot k }{ 1\cdot(k+2) } = \frac{3k}{k+2}$$
The expression equivalent to the initial one appears an identity.